# Filtro com média de valores unicos em lista de dicionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, filtro, dicionário

Estou com a seguinte lista de dicionário em Python 3.7:

```
a = [
    {'linha': 0,  'porcentagem': 1.0,   'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 8,  'porcentagem': 1.0,   'id': 7,  'nome': 'teste'},
    {'linha': 12, 'porcentagem': 1.0,   'id': 8,  'nome': 'testerino'},
    {'linha': 18, 'porcentagem': 1.0,   'id': 9,  'nome': 'joão'}, 
    {'linha': 7,  'porcentagem': 0.624, 'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 23, 'porcentagem': 0.624, 'id': 10, 'nome': 'mais um teste'},
    {'linha': 2,  'porcentagem': 0.439, 'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 10, 'porcentagem': 0.439, 'id': 7,  'nome': 'teste'},
    {'linha': 13, 'porcentagem': 0.439, 'id': 8,  'nome': 'testerino'},
    {'linha': 19, 'porcentagem': 0.439, 'id': 9,  'nome': 'joão'},
    {'linha': 1,  'porcentagem': 0.418, 'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 9,  'porcentagem': 0.418, 'id': 7,  'nome': 'teste'},
    {'linha': 15, 'porcentagem': 0.418, 'id': 8,  'nome': 'testerino'},
    {'linha': 20, 'porcentagem': 0.418, 'id': 9,  'nome': 'joão'},
    {'linha': 5,  'porcentagem': 0.294, 'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 17, 'porcentagem': 0.294, 'id': 8,  'nome': 'testerino'},
    {'linha': 6,  'porcentagem': 0.277, 'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 22, 'porcentagem': 0.277, 'id': 9,  'nome': 'joão'}
]
```

Eu gostaria de obter a seguinte saída:

```
[
    {'linha': 6,  'porcentagem': 0.509, 'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 9,  'porcentagem': 0.619, 'id': 7,  'nome': 'teste'},]
    {'linha': 17, 'porcentagem': 0.537, 'id': 8,  'nome': 'testerino'},
    {'linha': 22, 'porcentagem': 0.534, 'id': 9,  'nome': 'joão'},
    {'linha': 23, 'porcentagem': 0.624, 'id': 10, 'nome': 'mais um teste'}
]
```

**Importante** notar que a `linha` não é um dado relevante, o que eu preciso mesmo é: **id**, **nome** e **porcentagem**.

Eu consegui um resultado semelhante com o seguinte código:

```
b = list({r['id']: r for r in a}.values())
```

Porém o resultado foi simplesmente as ultimas ocorrências de tais valores, mas aqui entra o ponto mais importante, eu preciso da **média** de todos os valores daquele **id**, ou seja, a média de `[1.0, 0.624, 0.439, 0.418, 0.294, 0.277]` (valores de bruno, id 3) é `0.509` e é este o valor que deve aparecer na nova listagem, é um filtro com a média para cada um dos elementos repetidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `pandas`, uma biblioteca do Python que trabalha com DataFrames, é possível solucionar este problema facilmente.

```
import pandas as pd


a = [
    {'linha': 0,  'porcentagem': 1.0,   'id': 3,  'nome': 'bruno'},
    {'linha': 8,  'porcentagem': 1.0,   'id': 7,  'nome': 'teste'},
    ...
    {'linha': 22, 'porcentagem': 0.277, 'id': 9,  'nome': 'joão'}
]

# Transforma seus dados de `a` em um DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

>>> print(df)
    id  linha           nome  porcentagem
0    3      0          bruno        1.000
1    7      8          teste        1.000
...
17   9     22           joão        0.277
```

Depois é só agrupar (`groupby`) os dados das colunas `nome` e `id` e deixar como regra para a coluna `porcentagem` tirar a média:

````
df_gb = df.groupby(['nome', 'id']).agg({'porcentagem':'mean'})

>>> print(df_gb)
                  porcentagem
nome          id             
bruno         3      0.508667
joão          9      0.533500
mais um teste 10     0.624000
teste         7      0.619000
testerino     8      0.537750
```
````

Comment: Como eu converto estes valores para uma lista de dicionário novamente? Utilizei o `new_df_gb = df_gb.to_dict()`, porém ele cria uma lista com um único dicionário com a chave `porcentagem` e dentro dele uma lista com os dicionários onde as chaves são uma `tupla` com **id** e **nome** e valor a **porcentágem**. isso já me ajudou a avançar, porém gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de converter diretamente.

Comment: @bruno101, para converteres num dicionário como tens na pergunta e usando o exemplo da resposta podes simplesmentes fazer no fim: `df_gb.reset_index().round({'porcentagem': 3}).to_dict(orient='recods')`, e ficas com `[{'nome': 'bruno', 'porcentagem': 0.509, 'id': 3}, {'nome': 'joão', 'porcentagem': 0.534, 'id': 9}, {'nome': 'mais um teste', 'porcentagem': 0.624, 'id': 10}, {'nome': 'teste', 'porcentagem': 0.619, 'id': 7}, {'nome': 'testerino', 'porcentagem': 0.538, 'id': 8}]`

Comment: @Miguel e @AlexCiuffa, deu super certo, já havia ouvido falar dessa biblioteca `pandas` porém usei pouco, obrigado pela ajuda, vou olhar com mais atenção pra essa biblioteca.